# How to set the title of Android toolbar from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I would like to do something like this:

```
if (total != 0) {
    percentage = String.valueOf((count * 100) / total);
    Log.e("Percentage", percentage);
    myActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Progress: " + percentage + "%.");
}
```

However, I can't call `getSupportActionBar()` because it says `Non-static method 'getSupportActionBar()' cannot be referenced from a static context`. How can I solve this?

**Update**

This is the method inside my public class where I'd like to call the above code;

```
     @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

         }
         });
         }
```

Comment: Why not creating custom Listener to set title in Activity from another class instead of calling it using Activity instance.

Comment: Seems like your code block is inside a static method.

Comment: are you calling  myActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Progress: " + percentage + "%.");  this line from fragment  class ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K - How to do it? I don't know how to solve the question, that is why I ask.

Comment: @sohan shetty Not a fragment, but from another Java class. I have its context but still don't know how to change the title from there.

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K How exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to other answers, but none of them fit what I wanted.

I solved it by moving the code to the activity in question and setting the title from there. However, the main change was to post the percentage value from a **listener** method, in my case: **onItemCheckBoxChecked**. This meant that every time a user checked a box (could be other listeners in case of a textview or something else) the percentage was calculated in real time. I also made the percentage variable public.

Answer (score 0):

Casting your activity can resolve your problem. Suppose your Activity Name is YourCustomActivity. Now cast the Activity like below. Hope it will work.

```
    YourCustomActivity activity=(YourCustomActivity)myActivity;
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Please Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Sorry what is "myActivity" in this case? You mentioned that my activity name is YourCustomActivity (which is myActivity in my case)... Please help me understand.

Comment: You mentioned in your question    myActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Progress: " + percentage + "%.");  What is myActivity in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass activity parameter to another class and use activities funcitons like below;

```
public class CityModel {

    Activity activity;

    public CityModel(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    private void doIt() {
        ((YourActivity) activity).changeTitle("New Title");
    }

}
```

And define this class instance like below;

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CityModel model = new CityModel(this); // this-> Your activity.
     }

     public void changeTitle(String newTitle){
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle(newTitle);
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Because `getSupportActionBar()` is not static method. If you are using this method in static class or static method then you will get below error.

> Non-static method `getSupportActionBar()` cannot be referenced from a static context

If you want to common method for it you can make one think create public method in your activity and call in your `fragments`.

```
public void setToolBar(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

If you have Activity, simply you can call below code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Edit My Code :

```
public static void setToolbar(final AppCompatActivity activity,String title){
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

Edit Code : 
**My RecyclerViewAdapter class :**

```
public class ExploreGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExploreGalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private ArrayList<ExploreGalleryModel> exploreGalleryModelArrayList;
    //    private String status;


    public ExploreGalleryAdapter(AppCompatActivity activity, final ArrayList<ExploreGalleryModel> exploreGalleryModelArrayList, final String status) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.exploreGalleryModelArrayList = exploreGalleryModelArrayList;
//        this.status = status;
    }

  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

     }
            });

}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I can't access the activity's toolbar from another public class - how to solve this?

Comment: can you post your public class code, So i can check it.

Comment: It is a very big class and I can't post the whole thing here for other reasons. However, I am calling the code in question from when a checkbox is checked. So, I want the percentage to be real-time... Check my edited question now.

Comment: I just saw your updated answer, how to call this? It throws an error when I call it like  setToolbar(myActivity, percentage); - the error is "Expression expected".

Comment: ClassName.setToolbar(myActivity, percentage); Like that, You can call it.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work - the same error "Expression expected". Please check my updated question now.

Comment: You are calling this method in adapter?

Comment: Please check my newer update again - I am calling this under [@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {]